# get coördinates as variables from openlayer 3 map

Tags: openlayers-3

For my project i want to fill a text box with the x and y coördinates whenever i click in the map. i have the coördinates displayed on my screen with this this standard code:

```
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    target: document.getElementById('location'),
    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(5),
    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
  });
```

so i thought: if i use mousePositionControl as the variable for the x and y coordinate i get this in the textbox. So i tried this:

```
map.on('click', function() {
document.getElementById("coördinates").value = mousePositionControl;
});
```

but the result i get in the text box is this: [object Object]

Can somebody help me out with this problem?

Comment: String representation of an object of type `ol.control.MousePosition` is "[object Object]" so the code does exactly what you're asking it to do. The `click` handler receives the `event` object which already contains the coordinates of the pixel clicked so there's no need to involve a control.

Comment: is element `location` showing `x` and `y`. Why do you need to get `x` and `y` second time for element `coördinates`?

Comment: As a side note, "coördinates" and "coöperate" are written as "coordinates" and "cooperate" in English.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured it out by myself. I asked for the full element and striped and replaced that so I got what I got.

The code:

```
map.on('click', function() {
  var show = document.getElementById("location").innerHTML;
  var clean = show.replace('<div class="custom-mouse-position">', "");
  var clean_again = clean.replace('</div>', "");
  var split = clean_again.split(',');
});
```

Comment: You should not be processing html code as strings; it's not clean and could fail with some browsers or in future versions. It is recommended instead to work with the DOM to select the element you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
map.on('click', function(evt){
    document.getElementById('coördinates').innerHTML = evt.coordinate.join(", ");
});
```

Comment: Some comment as to why this fixes the problem would make this a far better answer